# Download file on clicking url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, download

I have a absolute file url.

```
let fileUrl="https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/aggregator/merchant/docs/45.txt?st=2018-06-11T10%3A09%3A43Z&se=2018-06-12T10%3A09%3A43Z&sp=r&sv=2017-04-17&sr=c&sig=ugiw0CuNXr0".
```

On clicking of a button, this file needs to get downloaded.

```
<button onClick={()=> {}>Download</button>
```

How can I achieve this using reactjs?

Comment: <a href="https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/aggregator/merchant/docs/45.txt?st=2018-06-11T10%3A09%3A43Z&se=2018-06-12T10%3A09%3A43Z&sp=r&sv=2017-04-17&sr=c&sig=ugiw0CuNXr0" >Download</a>

Comment: Are you sure your file path is correct.??. Just check it out

Comment: I have deliberately given a wrong url. It is just as an example.

Comment: Put your file in your assets.And give your file path in href. And try to get download. Then <a href="./assets/examplefile.xlxs" >Download</a>

Comment: As I said, the file is not local. In fact, I won't even have the file. All I get is the file url, not the actual file.

Answer (score 1):

Just link to it.

```
<a href={fileUrl}>Download</a>
```

Comment: This opens the file in browser. I don't want that. I need to download the file.

Comment: Then configure the server to send the correct [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header

Comment: I get the url as part of a json object. Eg. response={name:"abc",age:12,url=https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/aggregator/merchant/docs/45.txt?st=2018-06-11T10%3A09%3A43Z&se=2018-06-12T10%3A09%3A43Z&sp=r&sv=2017-04-17&sr=c&sig=ugiw0CuNXr0"}.

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to not do it programatically:

```
<a href={fileUrl} download>
  Download
</a>
```

If you want to go down the dark route of making it compatible on more browsers you need to fetch the file via ajax, create a blob, create a url from the blob, create an anchor element and assign the blob url, then trigger a click on it.

Or as @Quentin says if cross-origin is blocked then I would prefer to proxy to the file via your server on the same domain and still use the download attribute `href="/api/fileproxy?url=http://...."`.

Comment: **Danger**: This HTML is invalid. A `<button>` element cannot appear inside a link

Comment: The `download` attribute is generally not supported for cross-origin requests and the URL is an absolute URL.

Comment: I do not get the file. I only get the file url from the server as part of a json object

Answer (score 0):

use window.open(fileUrl) - will download ;

Comment: I do not want it to open in browser. I want to download it.

Comment: Whats the format of file, i mean file extension. excel and docx will download automatically, but image and pdf will open in new window. If you want to downlaod even pdf and image then set proper content type at server side

Comment: It could be any of the following .pdf,.img,.doc,.txt

Comment: something like this response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
        response.setContentType("application/zip");

Comment: The file url is a part of a application/json response. Eg: {name:'abc',age:'12',url:"https://dummyurl.txt"}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795394/download-file-on-clicking-url/50795882#50795882 go below for answer

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

```
<a href={fileUrl}><button>Download</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay to be precise you can follow below steps (this is in java)
1. Write new api which reads file into ByteArrayOutputStream and set the proper response type (File name and path will be requsted by Client)
    Eg :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = dao.readFIle(filename, filepath);

    String filename = filename+"."+fileextension;
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
    response.setContentType("application/zip");
        response.getOutputStream().write(baos.toByteArray());
        response.flushBuffer();
        baos.close();
```

2. Call that api form client by sending filename and path as attributes

Comment: The file url that I get is an absolute file url, not the actual file itself. Also, I am not aware of java. If you could help me using javascript, I'd really appreciate that!

Comment: Javascript it can only work in the way what i explained above. I.e view for pdf and Images and download for docx and excel formats. Ask your server side developer help to do above coding.